# Laravel S3 upload - damaged file, and not under the right directory

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to upload files to the `/logos` directory in my S3 bucket, but whenever I upload it, two things happen:

1. The file gets stored in the root directory
2. The file is corrupted whenever I try to download it directly from the AWS console, meaning that the file is corrupted anyways

This is how my code currently looks like:

```
$validated = $request->validate([
            'logo' => ['required', 'file', 'mimes:jpeg,png', 'max:2048'],
]);
...
if($request->hasFile('logo')){
            $file = $request->file('logo');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileName = time() . $extension;
            $path = Storage::disk('s3')->put($fileName, 'logos/');
            if (!$path) {
                dd('Failed to upload logo file.');
            }

            $validated['logo'] = $path;
        }
...
```

How can I correctly upload files and store them in the desired directory?

Comment: you're doing it wrong! in the put method, first parameter is for path + filename and the second parameter is for the content to put! It should be like: ``put('logos/' . $fileName, 
 $file);``

Comment: @OMiShah I just tried what you told me, and in AWS a file named "logos" is created, and then the file gets "uploaded," unfortunately, its still corrupted the png file that was uploaded, for some reason.

Comment: can you try``file_get_contents($file)`` as the 2nd parameter and let me know? Alternatively, you can use ``putFileAs('logos', $file, $fileName);`` instead of ``put()``.

Comment: @OMiShah almost! But `file_get_contents` was missing indeed.

Comment: If you will only provide folder name in the 1st parameter (without file name) and $file as 2nd parameter: ``->put('logos', $file);``, it will work. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is the following:

```
if($request->hasFile('logo')){
            $file = $request->file('logo');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileName = time() . $extension;
            $path = "logos/".$fileName; // we specify the path here
            $t = Storage::disk('s3')->put($path, file_get_contents($file)); // we use "file_get_contents" here to upload the file.
            if (!$t) {
                dd('Failed to upload logo file.');
            }

            $validated['logo'] = $path;
        }
```

Comment: What did you change? What was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue chage your code to be like this:

// Store the file in the "uploads" directory on S3

```
$uploadedFile = $request->file('file');
Storage::disk('s3')->put('uploads/' . $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName(), file_get_contents($uploadedFile));
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code according to below code. This will upload your image to logos directory inside s3 disk. I used `storeAs()` instead of using `put()`

```
if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {
        $file = $request->file('logo');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = time() . $extension;
        $path = $file->storeAs('logos', $fileName, 's3');
        if (!$path) {
            dd('Failed to upload logo file.');
        }

        $validated['logo'] = $path;

    }
```